# PyQT Version to suit Python 3.4.4

Tags: python, pyqt

Is there a PyQt version that is compatible with Python 3.4.4 as the binary installers are unavailable for 3.4.4 on here: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download. I tried installing PyQt5 but it seems to throw the error that a compatible version is not found when i try to install from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQt5.4.1 should be compatible - download from pyqt-sourceforge:

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/

furthermore, when using:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

it should find a compatible version for you ;)

Comment: where do i need to run pip install PyQt5 from

Comment: I have tried to run it within the Python34 directory in windows command prompt but it says that it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement